# How can I have multiple Directives call the the same promise in a service, only once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have more than one custom directive calling a promise inside the same function in a service that is getting data with a promise. This function inside the service gets hit 4 times (because of the 4 directives calling it). This is the issue. I only want this to be called once, instead of 4 different times. How can I do this?

Also, I'm sorry, I can't provide my code. It's simply a service calling a promise, then returning that kinda like so

Service:

```
return {
  GetData: function() {
    return processData.then(function(response){
      return response
    });
```

`processData` is just caching being done earlier in the file, where I get my data with `$http.get`.

Directives:

```
serviceName.GetData().then(function(response){
  //Do Stuff and what not
})
```

Comment: Why not call that particular function inside a controller, store the retrieved data on the controller scope in a scope variable and bind that variable to the directives instead of calling the function in each one of them? Additionally you can add an `ng-if="dataReady"` on your directives to add them only when the data becomes available.

Comment: SO is a site for enthusiast and professional developer and we like to keep it professional. Using all caps and things like "lol" are not that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can store the promise object and it can be accessed numerous times with `then()`

```
var promise = null;

return {
  GetData: function() {
    if (!promise) {
      promise = proccessData.then(function(response) {
        return response
      });
    }
    return promise;
  }
```

The first directive that accesses this will set the promise variable and all others will then access the same promise